# What data structure can I use to free memory within a contiguous stretch of memory?

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, memory-management, tree

I would like to simulate a population over time and keep a genealogy of the individuals that are still alive (I don't need to keep data about dead lineages). Generations are discrete and non-overlapping. For simplicity, let's assume that reproduction is asexual and each individual has exactly one parent. Here is a class `Individual`

```
class Individual
{
public:
   size_t nbChildren;
   const Individual* parent;

   Individual(const Individual& parent);
};
```

In my `Population` class, I would have a vector for the current offsprings and of the current parents (the current parents being the offsprings of the previous generation).

```
class Population
{
private:
  std::vector<Individual*> currentOffsprings;
  std::vector<Individual*> currentParents;

public:
  addIndividual(const Individual& parent) // Is called from some other module
  {
      Individual* offspring = new Individual(parent);
      currentOffsprings.push_back(offspring);
  }

  void pruneDeadLineages() // At the end of each generation, get rid of ancestors that did not leave any offsprings today
  {
    // Collect the current parents that have not left any children in the current generation of offsprings
    std::queue<Individual*> individualsWithoutChildren; // FIFO structure
    for (auto& currentParent : currentParents)
    {
      if (currentParent->nbChildren() == 0)
      {
        individualsWithoutChildren.push(currentParent);
      }
    }

    // loop through the FIFO to get rid of all individuals in the tree that don't have offspring in this generation
    while (individualsWithoutChildren.size() != 0)
    {
      auto ind = individualsWithoutChildren.pop_front();
      if (ind->nbChildren == 0)
      {
        ind->parent.nbChildren--;
        if (ind->parent.nbChildren == 0)
        {
          individualsWithoutChildren.push(ind->parent);
        }
        delete ind;
      }
    }
  }

  void newGeneration() // Announce the beginning of a new generation from some other module
  {
    currentParents.swap(currentOffsprings); // Set offsprings as parents
    currentOffsprings.resize(0);            // Get rid of pointers to parents (now grand parents)
  }

  void doStuff() // Some time consuming function that will run each generation
  {
    for (auto ind : currentOffspings)
    {
      foo(ind);
    }
  }
};
```

Assuming that the slow part of my code will be looping through the individuals in the `doStuff` method, I would like to keep individual contiguous in memory and hence

```
  std::vector<Individual*> currentOffsprings;
  std::vector<Individual*> currentParents;
```

would become

```
  std::vector<Individual> currentOffsprings;
  std::vector<Individual> currentParents;
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to consume memory for ancestors that did not leave any offspring in the current generation. In other words, I don't want to keep whole vectors of length of the number of individuals per generation in the population for each generation. I thought I could implement a destructor of `Individual` that does nothing, so that the `Individuals` of the grand parent generation do not get killed at the line `currentOffsprings.resize(0);` in `void Population::newGeneration()`. Then in `void Population::pruneDeadLineages()`, I would explicitly delete the individuals with a method `Individual::destructor()` instead of using `delete` or `Individual::~Individual()`.

Is it silly? Would it be memory safe (or yield to segmentation fault or memory leaks)? What other option do I have to 1) make sure that current generations individuals are contiguous in memory and 2) I can free the memory within this contiguous stretch of memory for ancestors that did not leave any offsprings?

Comment: Would shared or weak pointers be an option for you here? Could run some simple cleanup on an interval while keeping vector memory preallocations in place

Comment: @PaulRenton I have no experience working with shared and weak pointers but I feel like they would not help to ensure that `Individuals` are contiguous in the memory but I might be wrong. Thanks

Comment: If you want it to be contiguous then allocate a pool of these objects and draw the pointers from there using Weak Pointer references. Alternatively, override a new operator and create a pool of memory that is guaranteed to be contiguous when you allocate the objects you care about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why do you need to have your `Individual`s stored contiguously in memory.

Since you'll have to remove some of them and add others at each generation, you'll have to perform a reallocation for the whole bunch of `Individual`s in order to keep them contiguous in memory.

But anyway, I will not question what you want to do.

---

I think the easiest way is to let `std::vector` do the things for you. No need of pointers.

At each next generation, you move the offsprings from `currentOffsprings` to `currentParents` and you [clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) the `currentOffsprings`.
Then, for each parent that do not have any children in the current generation, you can just use [erase()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) from `std::vector` to remove them and consequently let the `std::vector` taking care of keeping its elements contiguous.

Better than 100 words, something like:

```
void Population::newGeneration()
{
    currentParents.swap(currentOffsprings);
    currentOffsprings.clear();
}

void Population::pruneDeadLineages()
{
    currentParents.erase(std::remove_if(currentParents.begin(), currentParents.end(), [](const Individual & ind){return ind.nbChildren == 0;}), currentParents.end());
}
```

Of course it assumes that the parents and offsprings are defined in `Population` as:

```
std::vector<Individual> currentParents;
std::vector<Individual> currentOffsprings;
```

**Note:** As `std::remove_if` moves the elements to remove at the end of the container, the elements to keep stays contiguous and there is thus no reallocation when performing the erasing.

This way your two requirements (keep `Individual`s contiguous in memory and get rid of dead lineages) will be filled, without doing weird things with destructors,...

But as you have two `std::vector`, you are assured to have `currentOffsprings` stored contiguously in memory, same thing for `currentParents`.
But the two `std::vector`s are absolutely not guaranteed to be contiguous each other (But I think you are already aware of this and that it is not what you want).

*<sub>Let me know if I have misunderstood your actual problem</sub>*